Is there a way to use MSI for storage account with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage package?
I'm deprecating the connection string of storage account and use MSI to authenticate. My service is using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage package to do all the operations (mainly table related). I know this is a legacy package, and upgrading it to new supported SDK (like Azure.Data.Tables) would make it easy to use MSI, but we don't want to upgrade the SDK now cause it involves lots of code change.
I tried to use code below:
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var accessToken = credential.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { "https://storage.azure.com/.default" }));

var tokenCredential = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.TokenCredential(initialToken: accessToken.Token);

StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
var tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(tableEndpoint), storageCredentials);
_table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
_table.CreateIfNotExists(tableRequestOptions);


But it reports the error "Token credential is not supported for this service".
It's strange because I can use a tokenCredential to construct the StorageCredentials but I couldn't use it.
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!


Is there a way to use MSI for storage account with the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage package?

You can use the code below to create an Azure Table storage from the package of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.
You need both packages (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication) to execute the code below. Here are the package references and installation commands:
To install:
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication --version 1.6.2
dotnet add package WindowsAzure.Storage --version 9.3.3


Note: Both packages were deprecated. for your information.

Package reference:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Code:
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string accountName = "venkat123";
        string tableName = "sampletab";

        await createTable(accountName, tableName);

        Console.WriteLine("Table created successfully!");
    }

    public static async Task createTable(string accountName, string tableName)
    {
        string tableEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net/", accountName);
        var token = await new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/");
        var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(token);
        var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
        var tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(tableEndpoint), storageCredentials);
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
        table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
    }
}

The above code creates a table in Azure Table Storage using Managed Identity with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient.
Output:
Table created successfully!


Portal:


This can also be done without using "Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" and using "Azure.Identity" instead:
csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

code:
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace MsiPoc
{
    public class StorageMsi
    {
        public const string accountName = "ddspocstorage1";
        public const string tableName = "sampletable";

        DefaultAzureCredential cred { get; set; }

        ILogger logger { get; set; }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using ILoggerFactory factory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
            var consoleLogger = factory.CreateLogger<StorageMsi>();

            StorageMsi storageMsi = new StorageMsi(consoleLogger);
            await storageMsi.CreateTable(accountName, tableName);

            Console.WriteLine("Table created successfully!");
        }

        public StorageMsi(ILogger s_logger)
        {
            logger = s_logger;

            string userAssignedClientId = "uami-or-sami-client-id";
            cred = new DefaultAzureCredential(
                new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
                {
                    ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId
                });
        }

        public async Task CreateTable(string accountName, string tableName)
        {
            AccessToken token = await cred.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(["https://storage.azure.com/"]));
            string tableEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net/", accountName);
            logger.LogInformation($"token start: {token.Token.Substring(0, 8)}");

            //need to use constructor overload for TokenCredential here for token renewal
            var tokenCredential = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.TokenCredential(token.Token);
            var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);

            // Create a table client for interacting with the table service
            var tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(tableEndpoint), storageCredentials);
            var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
            table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
}

I tested this using Azure Functions as the compute. I created a user-assigned managed identity and assigned it to the Azure Function. It works as expected.

Please note: initially I did not specify the UAMI/SAMI client id explicitly, and just used new DefaultAzureCredential(). The managed identity failed to load in this case, and I got this error: {"statusCode":400,"message":"Unable to load the proper Managed Identity.","correlationId":"REDACTED"}
